# How do facebook & instagram update the likes count?

Tags: facebook, react-native, instagram

I'm facing an issue with `state` variables, `this.setState({})` method updating the whole page while updating the `like` count on the card, but `Facebook & Instagram` are also using the same technology(if I'm not wrong), `react native`, I wonder how are they doing it.

When clicking a card in my FB feed, it is just updating the count, not the page. But in my program, its updating the whole page. I mean it is re-rendering the page while updating `state` variables.

Anybody know how to do it? 
Thanks

## Edits

This is exactly my problem, please see this [video](https://youtu.be/4mJ_7HvxjRc), all card is refreshing while clicking a heart.

```
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
...
class GridViewClass extends Component {
...
_renderRow(item, sec, i) {
    let addToFavourites = true;
    let iconColor = "white";
    for(const i in this.props.favoriteTopics){
      if(item.topicName === this.props.favoriteTopics[i].topicName){
        addToFavourites = false;
        iconColor = "red";
      }
    }
    // console.log("item values",item.topicName,item.topicDescription);
    return (
      <View key={"gridItemContainer_"+item.topicName+this.props.parentKey} style={styles.gridItem}>
        <View key={"viewGrid_" + item.topicName+this.props.parentKey} style={styles.gridContainer}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={"touch_" + item.topicName+this.props.parentKey} onPress={() => this.props.openSubCat(item.topicId, item.topicName)}>
            <View key={"touchableContainer"+item.topicId+this.props.parentKey}>
              <ProgressiveImage imageKey={"imageGrid_" + item.topicName+this.props.parentKey} source={{ uri: item.imageurl }} resizeMode={'stretch'} thumbnailresizeMode={'cover'} thumbnail={require("../../images/placeholder.png")} style={{ width: 170, height: 90, padding: 4, alignSelf: 'center' }} />
              <View key={"textContainer"+item.topicId+this.props.parentKey} style={styles.textcontainer}>
                <Text style={styles.catname}>{item.topicName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>{item.topicDescription}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <Icon key={"iconKey"+item.topicName+this.props.parentKey} name="favorite" ref={(ref)=>this.storeRowRef(ref)} size={30} color={iconColor} onPress={(event) => addToFavourites?this.addToMyTopics(event,item.topicName):this.removeFromMyTopics(event,item.topicName)}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code to back this question up, it's kinda hard to figure out your problem. It shouldn't be doing that unless the state is in your main component.

Comment: Are you talking about the website? No, that is not based on React ... React is a framework to build mobile applications, and the website is not one.

Comment: I'm talking about mobile application build with React-native @CBroe

Comment: you need to add your code

Comment: side note: you could add a "break;" in the for loop, looks like you may be doing some unneccessary cycles. anyway, isn´t that only one element?

Comment: it may have more, just like a facebook feed. @luschn

Comment: i know, but if all you do is set two variables to a fixed value, it is pointless to continue the loop if one the topic name was found once.